# Displaying view-options in a logical way

Tags: gui-design

I have a search result screen on which I'm having trouble placing the available view options:
1. View results in list or on map.
2. Apply one of 3 filters. 
Currently I'm considering the solution below as two rows of tabs, but I don't like how the two functions appear as the same kind of thing. I would appreciate any feedback/suggestions.

[image: Layout]

Comment: Please edit your question to pose a general UX problem, not one that is so specific to your situation that it wouldn't be very helpful to someone else reading the question and answers.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to give a suggestion without knowing what filters are for. I can definitely recommend this article though: https://uxplanet.org/mobile-ux-design-user-friendly-search-51e5f78f5a1e#.j5pz4v9f5

With the limited knowledge I have I can see scope bars working for List & Map. Tabs with two rows are pretty hard on most users so I wouldn't attempt that.

Think about using the filters to display results in "categories". An example can be found here: https://www.nngroup.com/articles/mobile-faceted-search/

[image: Refining by categories]

This is what I mean by a scope bar: https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-bars/search-bars/

[image: Scope Bar]

Comment: Thanks for you answer and for sharing screenshots! I'm going to try the Amazon method.

Answer (score 0):

Foursquare has a solution to this. Notice in the background of the image, there's this small map icon. By default you see a list but by clicking the map icon, you change to a map view.

[image]